# LINQ get one to many relationship with object and with a list

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have 2 tables called SampleQuestions and SampleQuestionsAnswers.

Table Details

SampleQuestions - SampleQuestionId, Question

SampleQuestionsAnswers - SampleQuestionsAnswerId,SampleQuestionId, Answer

One Question has many Answers.

I have a C# class like this

```
    public class SampleJobQuestions
    {
      [Key]
      public int SampleJobQuestionId { get; set; }
      public string Question { get; set; }
      public List<SampleJobQuestionAnswers> Answers { get; set; }
    }
```

Using Entity Framework, How can I get list of SampleJobQuestions objects with the answers as a list inside in each object?

Comment: Do you use DatabaseFirst approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use EF Core

```
public class SampleQuestion
{
    public int SampleQuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<SampleQuestionAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class SampleQuestionAnswer
{
    public int SampleQuestionAnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// Type configuration for SampleQuestion entity
public class SampleQuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SampleQuestion>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SampleQuestion> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("SampleQuestion");

        builder.Property(q => q.SampleQuestionId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

        builder.HasMany(q => q.Answers); // Check that answers has links to questions in database
    }
}

// Type configuration for SampleQuestionAnswer entity
public class SampleQuestionAnswerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SampleQuestionAnswer>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SampleQuestionAnswer> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("SampleQuestionAnswer");

        builder.Property(b => b.SampleQuestionAnswerId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
    }
}

// Create special context
public class QuestionDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SampleQuestion> SampleQuestions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SampleQuestionAnswer> SampleQuestionsAnswers { get; set; }

    public QuestionDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
         : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .ApplyConfiguration(new SampleQuestionConfiguration())
            .ApplyConfiguration(new SampleQuestionAnswerConfiguration());

        SampleQuestions.Include(x => x.Answers);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        QuestionDbContext qContext = new QuestionDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<QuestionDbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer("connectionString")
            .Options);
        var questions = qContext.SampleQuestions.AsNoTracking(); // not elegant, but it will work
    }
}
```